# Librosa generates heavy MFCC feature array

Tags: arrays, audio, mfcc, librosa

I've a 1.25gb .acc audio file size.

My problem is when i'm trying to get features using **librosa.feature.mfcc**

Configuration

```
SampleRate = 22050
Hop = 512
n_mfcc features = 40
```

1. it takes hours running
2. uses a lot of memory

I'd like to know if there's a better faster/lighter way to extract mfcc features

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

MFCC features are computed per frame. If you have hop size 512, the frame size is only 1024 or 2048 values. So if you stream the AAC file and load small chucks of M*frame size, then you so not need to load it all into memory.

This can be done using Pysoundfile block processing:
https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/#block-processing

An alternative is to chop up your file into NN second long files, process them individually and then concatenate the results.